# Swift 5.5 test async Task in init

Tags: swift, concurrency

I would like to test if my init function works as expected. There is an async call in the init within a Task {} block. How can I make my test wait for the result of the Task block?

```
class ViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published private(set) var result: [Item]
        
    init(fetching: RemoteFetching) {
        self.result = []
        Task {
            do {
                let result = try await fetching.fetch()
                
                self.result = result // <- need to do something with @MainActor?
            } catch {
                print(error)   
            }
        }
    }  
}
```

Test:

```
func testFetching() async {
    let items = [Item(), Item()]
    let fakeFetching = FakeFetching(returnValue: items)

    let vm = ViewModel(fetching: FakeFetching())
        
    XCTAssertEqual(vm.result, [])
        
    // wait for fetching, but how?
        
    XCTAssertEqual(vm.result, items])
}
```

I tried this, but setting the items, only happens after the XCTWaiter. The compiler warns that XCTWaiter cannot be called with await, because it isn't async.

```
    func testFetching() async {
        let items = [Item(), Item()]
        let fakeFetching = FakeFetching(returnValue: items)

        let expectation = XCTestExpectation()

        let vm = ViewModel(fetching: FakeFetching())
        
        XCTAssertEqual(vm.result, [])
        
        vm.$items
            .dropFirst()
            .sink { value in
                XCTAssertEqual(value, items)
                expectation.fulfill()
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
        
        let result = await XCTWaiter.wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)
        
        XCTAssertEqual(result, .completed)
    }
```

Comment: Wait and expectation is correct. You're just using it wrong. Basically you are way overthinking this. You don't need an `async` test method. You don't need to call fulfill yourself. You don't need a Combine chain. Simply use a predicate expectation to wait until vm.result is set.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Expectation-and-wait is correct. You're just using it wrong.

You are way overthinking this. You don't need an `async` test method. You don't need to call `fulfill` yourself. You don't need a Combine chain. Simply use a predicate expectation to wait until `vm.result` is set.

Basically the rule is this: Testing an `async` method requires an `async` test method. But testing the asynchronous "result" of a method that happens to make an asynchronous call, like your `init` method, simply requires good old-fashioned expectation-and-wait test.

I'll give an example. Here's a reduced version of your code; the structure is essentially the same as what you're doing:

```
protocol Fetching {
    func fetch() async -> String
}
class MyClass {
    var result = ""
    init(fetcher: Fetching) {
        Task {
            self.result = await fetcher.fetch()
        }
    }
}
```

Okay then, here's how to test it:

```
final class MockFetcher: Fetching {
    func fetch() async -> String { "howdy" }
}

final class MyLibraryTests: XCTestCase {
    let fetcher = MockFetcher()
    func testMyClassInit() {
        let subject = MyClass(fetcher: fetcher)
        let expectation = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(
            predicate: NSPredicate(block: { _, _ in
                subject.result == "howdy"
            }), object: nil
        )
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 2)
    }
}
```

---

**Extra for experts:** A Bool predicate expectation is such a common thing to use, that it will be found useful to have on hand a convenience method that combines the expectation, the predicate, and the wait into a single package:

```
extension XCTestCase {
    func wait(
        _ condition: @escaping @autoclosure () -> (Bool),
        timeout: TimeInterval = 10)
    {
        wait(for: [XCTNSPredicateExpectation(
            predicate: NSPredicate(block: { _, _ in condition() }), object: nil
        )], timeout: timeout)
    }
}
```

The outcome is that, for example, the above test code can be reduced to this:

```
    func testMyClassInit() {
        let subject = MyClass(fetcher: fetcher)
        wait(subject.result == "howdy")
    }
```

Convenient indeed. In my own code, I often add an explicit assert, *even when it is completely redundant,* just to make it perfectly clear what I'm claiming my code does:

```
    func testMyClassInit() {
        let subject = MyClass(fetcher: fetcher)
        wait(subject.result == "howdy")
        XCTAssertEqual(subject.result, "howdy") // redundant but nice
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Slight variation on [Matt's excellent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt). In my case, I've broken out his extension method into even more granular extensions for additional convenience.

**Helper Framework**

```
public typealias Predicate = () -> Bool

public extension NSPredicate {

    convenience init(predicate: @escaping @autoclosure Predicate) {
        self.init{ _, _ in predicate() }
    }
}

public extension XCTNSPredicateExpectation {

    convenience init(predicate: @escaping @autoclosure Predicate, object: Any) {
        self.init(predicate: NSPredicate(predicate: predicate()), object: object)
    }

    convenience init(predicate: @escaping @autoclosure Predicate) {
        self.init(predicate: NSPredicate(predicate: predicate()))
    }

    convenience init(predicate: NSPredicate) {
        self.init(predicate: predicate, object: nil)
    }
}

public extension XCTestCase {

    func XCTWait(for condition: @escaping @autoclosure Predicate, timeout: TimeInterval = 10) {
        let expectation = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: condition())
        wait(for: [expectation], timeout: timeout)
    }
}
```

With the above in place, the OP's code can be reduced to this...

**Unit Test**

```swift
func testFetching() {

    let items = [Item(), Item()]

    let fakeFetching = FakeFetching(returnValue: items)

    let vm = ViewModel(fetching: FakeFetching())
 
    XCTWait(for: vm.items == items, timeout: 1)   
}
```

**Notes on Naming**

Above, I'm using a somewhat controversial name in calling my function `XCTWait`. This is because the `XCT` prefix should be considered reserved for Apple's `XCTest` framework.  However, the decision to name it this way stems from the desire to improve its discoverability.  By naming it as such, when a developer types `XCT` In their code editor, `XCTWait` is now presented as one of the offered auto-complete entries** making finding and using much more likely.

However, some purists may frown on this approach, citing if Apple ever added something named similar, this code may suddenly break/stop working (although unlikely unless the signatures also matched.)

As such, use such namings at your own discretion. Alternately, simply rename it to something you prefer/that meets your own naming standards.

(** *Provided it is in the same project or in a library/package they've imported somewhere above*)

Answer (score 0):

[Matt's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72363701/4850928) (and a few others) has one drawback - the test duration using `XCTNSPredicateExpectation`. The first condition check takes place **after waiting for 1 second**. Unit tests should **be fast**.

Therefore I created a global function (to match `XCTAssert` interface) that uses a repeating Timer to check a condition.

```swift
import XCTest

public func XCTAssertEventuallyTrue(
    _ condition: @escaping @autoclosure () -> Bool,
    pollInterval: TimeInterval = 0.01,
    timeout: TimeInterval = 1.0,
    file: StaticString = #filePath,
    line: UInt = #line
) async {
    let startDate = Date()
    
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        let timer = Timer(timeInterval: pollInterval, repeats: true, block: { timer in
            if condition() {
                finish(continuation: continuation, timer: timer)
            } else if abs(startDate.timeIntervalSinceNow) < timeout {
                XCTFail("Timeout exceeded", file: file, line: line)
                finish(continuation: continuation, timer: timer)
            }
        })
        RunLoop.main.add(timer, forMode: .default)
    }
}

private func finish(
    continuation: CheckedContinuation<(), Never>, 
    timer: Timer
) {
    timer.invalidate()
    continuation.resume()
}
```

The above can be easily extended with other cases, like `XCTAssertEventuallyFalse` or `XCTAssertEventuallyNotTrue` (yes, naming inspired with [Nimble](https://github.com/Quick/Nimble)).

And tests can look like this (which, by the way, nicely indicates that some async code is tested).

```swift
func testFetching() async {
    let items = [Item(), Item()]
    let fakeFetching = FakeFetching(returnValue: items)

    let vm = ViewModel(fetching: FakeFetching())

    await XCTAssertEventuallyTrue(vm.items == items)
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tnx to [matt](https://stackoverflow.com/users/341994/matt) this is the correct way. No need for async in the test function and just using a predicate did the job.

```
func testFetching() {
    let items = [Item(), Item()]
    let fakeFetching = FakeFetching(returnValue: items)

    let expectation = XCTestExpectation()

    let vm = ViewModel(fetching: FakeFetching())
    
    let pred = NSPredicate { _, _ in
        vm.items == items
    }
    let expectation = XCTNSPredicateExpectation(predicate: pred, object: vm)
    
    wait(for: [expectation], timeout: 1)
}
```

Comment: You've carried over the original declaration of `expectation`.