# Unit testing non-async function that uses async function

Tags: swift, unit-testing, swift-concurrency

I have recently updated some code to use Swift concurrency and am unable to work out how to modify my unit tests to support it.

Here's a representation of the code:

```
protocol AppStartupService {
    func doSomething()
}

class MyClass: AppStartupService {
    
    var dependency: MyClassesDependency
    
    init(dependency: MyClassesDependency) {
        self.dependency = dependency
    }
    
    func doSomething() {
        // This is where the problem is introduced
        // `Task` must be used to avoid marking the surrounding func as `async`
        // however this breaks concurrency for the unit test
        Task {
            await dependency.someAsyncFunc()
            // now the 'didSomethingAsync' flag has been set on a different thread, after the unit test has checked it
        }
    }
}

protocol MyClassesDependency {
    func someAsyncFunc() async
}
```

While this async function can be used in some instances where it is important to await its completion, in this case it is not important.

Furthermore, the call occurs in a function that cannot be declared `async` as it is a protocol requirement and this would be a large breaking change.

And representation of the test:

```
class MyClassesMockDependency: MyClassesDependency {
    
    var didSomethingAsync: Bool = false
    
    func someAsyncFunc() async {
        didSomethingAsync = true
    }
}

/// Verify that the dependency was called by `doSomething()`
func testMyClass() {
    let mockDependency = MyClassesMockDependency()
    let instance = MyClass(dependency: mockDependency)
    
    instance.doSomething()
    
    XCTAssertTrue(mockDependency.didSomethingAsync)
    // fail. It was checked too soon
}
```

Ideally I'd like to resolve this without

- Modifying `AppStartupService` protocol
- Using some artificial wait time in the unit tests

Can anyone suggest a modification to the test to achieve this?

Alternatively, is there some other bigger picture point I might have missed, or principle I'm violating?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See `XCTestExpectation`. https://www.swiftbysundell.com/articles/unit-testing-asynchronous-swift-code/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It strikes me that there are two issues:

1. Unit tests are for testing your function‘s interface, and your function is one that launches unstructured concurrency without providing any mechanism to know when it is complete. (More on that later.)

   So, it is curious to want to test an interface that your function does not provide. To my eye, it introduces a dissonance between the functionality and what you are testing. I would contend that it violates the very idea of a “unit test”.
2. The more fundamental question, though, is whether it is prudent to write a function launches an asynchronous task without providing any mechanism to know when that asynchronous task is done. Also, the same question applies to the protocol, namely whether it is good practice to write an interface/protocol where a future developer might not be able to reasonably infer that it is really an asynchronous process.

   Hey, we have all probably done this at one time or another, but, for me at least, more than once I have found myself needing to later refactor that code to add some mechanism to know when the work was done (for the sake of the app itself, not just for tests).

   Personally, as a rule, in our projects, we embrace the design principle that we do not write functions that do not provide a mechanism to know when the asynchronous work is done. We have never regretted that approach, and not-infrequently have thanked ourselves for doing that.

So, in short, I would advise changing the protocol to make it clear it is an asynchronous method. Ideally, I would suggest make it an `async` function. Or, if you *really* need it to be a non-`async` method, then give it an optional completion handler closure parameter. Either way, the protocol will now clearly indicate the underlying asynchronous nature of the method, it is testable, and it provides a mechanism that will likely be useful as your project evolves.

Comment: That's a really insightful reply, thanks for taking the time to share, it's appreciated.

I think your rule for providing a mechanism to inform of completion is a really sensible idea and I will endeavor to do the same.

I wonder, what would you advise regarding awaiting completion of execution that resulted from NotificationCenter? Or perhaps would you avoid that pattern entirely. I'm not a huge fan of the unstructured nature of it, however it is useful for bridging large distances in the code (perhaps that itself is an indication that refactoring is needed though)

Comment: Arguably, testing this end-to-end is not something covered by a single unit test. `NotificationCenter` is, fundamentally, a way for one unit to communicate to another, isolated, one. Theoretically, unit tests are a way to test a unit _in isolation_ of other units. So, in your hypothetical example, I might write one test that ensures that function _a_ posts a particular notification of a particular structure. And I might write another test that function _b_ does something when receiving a particular notification. If necessary, I might mock the notification center for the purpose of these tests.

Comment: Now, IMHO, that is not damning evidence of some problem in the design. We generally really like this sort of loose-coupling between subsystems. I'm just suggesting that it might not be a single unit test to verify the integration between these different subsystems.

Comment: On reflection I think the issue I'm looking at is with unit tests that have too broad a scope, and _are_ essentially more like integration tests. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

> Using some artificial wait time in the unit tests

The key word here is "artificial". The technique is to wait *for something specific* to be the case. In other words, don't merely add a timed delay; wait *for* `didSomethingAsync` to become `true`.

Comment: For code, see my https://stackoverflow.com/a/72363701/341994 (and other answers on that page).

Comment: That's a really helpful answer thanks. `XCTNSPredicateExpectation` is the key to unlocking the wait without having to modify the code to somehow fulfill an expectation.

Comment: It's so useful that I have a `waitFor` method on XCTestCase, which takes a Bool-result closure directly and builds the whole predicate expectation dance for me. So in your situation I would be able to write `waitFor { mockDependency.didSomethingAsync }` in the test.